# Want to get address after placing marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

The map is rendering and I'm able to drag the marker around, BUT I'm not sure why the event listeners are not giving me the location of the marker. Error is below.

Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Please can you help? My code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
 var map;
      function getLocation(){
            if(navigator.geolocation){
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, error);
            }else{
                myLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation API not supported in this browser, try another"
            }
        }
        function showPosition(position){
          var  myLocation = document.getElementById('livePos');
          myLocation.innerHTML = "Latitude:"+position.coords.latitude +
            "<br> Longitude" + position.coords.longitude;

            var lati = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
            
        }
    
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 51, lng: 0.19},
          zoom:8
        
        
        });

        getLocation()
             
        var lati = 51.516228;
        var long = 0.19003019999999998;
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lati,long);
        map.panTo(point);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        title: 'Here!'
        })

        var search = document.getElementById('search');

        search.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var lati = document.getElementById('lat').value;
        var long = document.getElementById('long').value; 
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lati,long);
        map.panTo(point);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        title: 'Here!'
        });
    
    
         
        

        });
    
    }
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'dragend', function(evt){
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latiLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</p>';
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(evt){
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 errors/typos in the posted code (found in the javascript console).

1. `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` on this line: `google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'dragend', function(evt) {`, because that is outside of the `initMap` callback function and runs before API has loaded.
2. `ReferenceError: error is not defined`
   (because it isn't defined in the posted code)
3. `ReferenceError: Marker is not defined`, javascript is case sensitive, that should be `marker` (not `Marker`).
4. On dragging: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`, on this: `evt.latiLng.lat().toFixed(3)`.  That is a typo, should be `evt.latLng`.

Fixing those, the posted code works (displays the correct coordinates of the initial marker in the `<div id="current">` (assuming you have one, you didn't post any CSS or HTML).

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4mhc763w/3/)

If you want to get the address based on the coordinates returned see [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_revgeo.html), if you drag the marker and click on it it will display the reverse geocoded address of the new position of the marker.

[image: screenshot of working map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, error);
  } else {
    myLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation API not supported in this browser, try another"
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var myLocation = document.getElementById('livePos');
  myLocation.innerHTML = "Latitude:" + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br> Longitude" + position.coords.longitude;

  var lati = position.coords.latitude;
  var long = position.coords.longitude;
}

function error(error) {
  alert("error in geolocation(" + error.code + ") " + error.message);
}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 51,
      lng: 0.19
    },
    zoom: 8
  });

  getLocation()

  var lati = 51.516228;
  var long = 0.19003019999999998;
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, long);
  map.panTo(point);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Here!'
  })

  var search = document.getElementById('search');

  search.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var lati = document.getElementById('lat').value;
    var long = document.getElementById('long').value;
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, long);
    map.panTo(point);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: point,
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      title: 'Here!'
    });
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</p>';
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="livePos"></div>
  <input id="lat" value="51.516228" />
  <input id="long" value="0.1900302" />
  <input id="search" type="button" value="search" />
  <br/>
  <div id="current"></div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```